# Delocalisation of the hydrogen nuclei

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

My question is related to the following article:

https://aeon.co/essays/why-the-empty-atom-picture-misunderstands-quantum-theory?fbclid=IwAR3b9f8Uxtgjq294Uj8Bv8t_wxb37XlUHX_tNSyIXyRScjQ3GeRwBQzBIHM

In there, the author states that

> The delocalisation of the hydrogen nuclei is even more impressive. They grow from a radius of 0.9 fm when seen as particles to clouds of about 23,000 fm.

Please, can you tell me how the 23,000 fm result is obtained?

Comment: seems to me it is a personal interpretation of the wavefunction of the writer of the article, that has little to do with mainstream physics.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the point which  he obscures so well, in classic unscrupulous popular science fashion: the cloud  he presents is around the center of mass, and he presents the jiggle of the nuclei in it: they are not fixed, so his approximation technique in his paper leads to UP "play", the 3nm and 23 nm radii, respectively. He might as well have taken the original nuclei to be pointlike, like the electrons. The crucial ratio is 23/179 for the proton clouds versus the overall molecule electron cloud. They are applying some type of energy equipartition argument...

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/740353/center-of-mass-in-hydrogen-atom).

Comment: The imagery of a hadronic radius of the nucleus "growing" to a marshmallow cloud of the nucleon with a "Bohr radius" 4 orders of magnitude larger is sadistic, clueless, and misleading--and would have driven me crazy before 1970, when I actually read such drivel... always shaking my fist. Anyway, you might devise scaling arguments to arrange ratios of ()∼180nm, ()∼23nm, ()∼3 nm, next to ratios of ()∼0.05GeV, ()~1 GeV, ()∼14GeV.

Comment: But ammonia is a messy non-hydrogenic molecule and their effective technique in the linked paper appears uncontrollable. You are meant to appreciate  all three *m×r* s are of the same order of magnitude, nevertheless...